# Logging into Draftkings

Tags: python, selenium, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to log into the Draftkings sportsbook using Mechanicalsoup. This is due to a friend's suggestion, but not sure if mechanicalsoup will work for me. The log in page does not seem to be a form but rather 2 input fields with a button to do the work.

The inspect of the page is shown below:
[inspect of draftkings log in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWXf0.png)

I was wondering if I need to use selenium for this project.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no form element on the page, then it is using JavaScript and MechanicalSoup may not be the best choice, because it doesn't handle JavaScript. See https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#form-submission-has-no-effect-or-fails.

Comment: Is selenium my best option then? I have never used it and was having some errors with  the webdriver in it.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Selenium, but it seems to be the most frequently recommended tool for when you need to handle JavaScript.